# Infinitely many solutions of a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the value(s) of a real parameter *k* so that the system of equations has infinitely many solutions.
>
> $x+y+z=1$
> $2x+ky+3z=-2$
> $3x+5y+kz=-1$

Please help, I don't know how to go about this. Would you have to try every combination of the equations until you get a contradiction?

Comment: You dont want a contradiction, this gives you empty solution. You want to find a $k$ such that one of the equation can be obtained as a linear combination of the other two equation.

Comment: What conditions have you learned for a system of equations having an infinite number of solutions? Start with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the first and second and subtract the third equation we have: $(k-4)(y-z) = 0$. Thus we require $k = 4$ to have infinite solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Firs you rewrite the system of equation as a matrix equation $Ax=b$. The system has a unique solution if and only if $\det(A)\neq0$. But since $\det A=(k-4)(k-1)=0$. So the solution is unique if and only if $k\neq 4$ and $k\neq 1$.

But if you check it further, when $k=1$ the system has no solution  while when $k=4$ the system has infinitely many solutions. So $k=4$ is the only answer.